# Select a node if a siblings child does not exist in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to select identifiers in this case 6789 that does NOT have a Metadata element

```
<dt class="document-metadata">Metadata</dt>
```

under the dd @class=document-manifest sibling which can be checked with either with the class or the text as it wont change.

```
<dt class="document-manifest">
    <a class="document" href="/Document/12345">12345</a>
</dt>
<dd class="document-manifest">
    <dl class="document-manifest-items">
        <dt class="document-summary">Document Summary</dt>
        <dd class="document-summary">
            <dl class="document-summary">
                <dt class="document-metadata">MetaData</dt>
            </dl>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</dd>
<dt class="document-manifest">
    <a class="document" href="/Document/6789">6789</a>
</dt>
<dd class="document-manifest">
    <dl class="document-manifest-items">
        <dt class="document-summary">Document Summary</dt>
        <dd class="document-summary">
            <dl class="document-summary">
            </dl>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</dd>
```

In this case it should just select the 6789 identifier.

I have tried a bunch of things cant seem to get it right.

Figured something like the following would work seems to return the id's regardless if it has metadata or not

```
//dt[@class='document-manifest']/a[not(../dd/dl/dd/dl/dt[@class='document-metadata'])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work, may be a better way to do it though

```
//dt[@class='document-manifest']/a[../following-sibling::*[1]/dl/dd[@class='document-summary']/dl/not(dt='MetaData')]
```

Comment: Should note that this didn't work in xpath 1.0 and I had to change the xpath processor to one that supported 2.0 (used saxon)